# Disable nesting level hints

Tags: intellij-idea, rider

After installing Rider 2020.1, such hints as shown in the screenshot appeared. There are many `+1` in grey showing up after different lines of code.

How do I disable them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your "+1". It seems to be the plugin [**CognitiveComplexity**](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12024-cognitivecomplexity) giving you that number. It's a counter which helps you on determining the complexity of the code you're writing. Pretty cool plugin I didn't know it. Disabling it will make the numbers disappear. I don't think you can let it enabled and avoid seeing numbers: it's the way it works to show you complexity cost.

To disable or enable plugins, go to Settings > Plugins, and then deselect CognitiveComplexity.

Comment: Thanks! I really forget about this plugin.

Comment: To show/hide the "+1", click the diamond `◇` near the method declaration.